# Where is sdkmanager's SDK located?

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, mobile, android-sdk-manager

Where is sdkmanager's SDK located? I am on MAC OSX High Sierra and everyone said it is on /Users//Library/Android/sdk or /Users//AppData/... but in reality I can not find Android folder or AppData in my OSX.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the path going into Android Studio -> Configure -> SDK Manager -> On the top left it should say SDK Path.

Comment: I'm using brew cask, no Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, within Android Studio, go to the Tools menu > Android > SDK Manager.

The app will then show you the path to your SDK. If you installed it using the defaults, it should be:

```
/Users/[your user name]/Library/Android/sdk
```

Comment: @FrankerZ I'm not install from Android Studio, just using brew cask

Comment: @user5436320 In that case, check for the SDK install path using the Tools menu > Android > SDK Manager.